# How to upload files to hdfs web page from terminal?

Tags: linux, hadoop, hdfs, webhdfs

I just started hadoop and doing hdfs configuration. I have done all the steps but this last part of uploading the file is not working.

I used this to make my directory, it works

```
    hadoop fs -mkdir /user/syed
```

But when i do :

```
    hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/syed/hadoopMR/input input
```

OR

```
    hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/syed/hadoopMR/input input
```

OR

```
    hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/syed/hadoopMR/input/file.txt user/syed/input
```

OR

```
    hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/syed/hadoopMR/input/file.txt input
```

OR

```
    hdfs dfs -put /home/syed/hadoopMR/input/file.txt input
```

It only creates an empty 'input' directory and when i specify 'file.txt' it gives nothing.

**This is being shown on the terminal:**

copyFromLocal: File /user/syed/input/input/fileA.txt.*COPYING* could only be written to 0 of the 1 minReplication nodes. There are 0 datanode(s) running and 0 node(s) are excluded in this operation.

Can you please guide me, i have a home task and i have already put so many hours into finding the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The data nodes are missing. When i format the name-node it gets assigned a new ID but the datanode does not get formatted and still has the old id.

1. stop-dfs.sh    // if hdfs running
2. hdfs namenode -format
3. rm -rvf /home/syed/hdfs/data/*

   // the path of data node is in your home/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml
4. start-dfs.sh

AND it should work !

Answer (score 0):

You are missing / before user. That is why you're unable to see the file. Try the below commands.

*To make directory use this command.*

```
hadoop fs -mkdir /user/syed
```

*To make the input directory in hadoop path.*

```
hadoop fs -mkdir /user/syed/input
```

*You can list the local path to check if the file is present.*

```
ls /home/syed/hadoopMR/input/
```

*Then use the following command to put the file to hadoop path.*

```
hdfs dfs -put /home/syed/hadoopMR/input/file.txt /user/syed/input
```

Hope this answers your question.